# Creating simple repeating number sequence in SPSS

Tags: syntax, spss

I want to create the following sequence in SPSS syntax. I've tried LOOP and DO REPEAT, but cannot figure out how to re-create this:

1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5

Comment: Show the code you tried and its results.

Comment: It is not very clear what you want to achieve: 3 variables for each number ? Do you already have the variables and want them populated ? Or you also need to create them ? Or maybe this is a string variable ? What is the stopping point ? Please post more details, and also the code (or pseudocode) you've tried

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really not clear enough, so I'm just guessing. Please edit your question so we can know if this is the right solution (and for the benefit of future readers).

If what you want is a variable that has the values 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, etc', Here is a way to get that:

```
compute MyVar=trunc(($casenum-1)/3)+1.
exe.
```